# Memory limitations of 32bit systems

Tags: vmware

I am on a 32bit Ubuntu System and as we know there is a memory limitation of 3.5GB at most. Is there a possibility to take advantage of the rest of the memory on my system (I have 8gb) by running vmware player and giving like 3gb to the system running in the player??

- My cpu is AMD Phenom II X6 1090T

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! This site works best if you ask *one* question at the time. Your last question, the differences, is already answered on this site (use the search function).

Comment: one question you mean right? ok but its not mandatory for someone to answer all of this i guess. My main question was about vmware and memory.

Comment: It's not about what's mandatory, it's about what's recommended and how to best use this infrastructure. I suggest that you edit your question to only include your main question then. If you want the other questions answered you should search the site for answers to them or ask them as separate questions.

Comment: Why not use PAE (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension)? 32-bits with more than 4 Gb is possible.

Comment: @VaiosArgiropoulos Please add such essential information to your question by editing it.

Comment: @Rinzwind Is it worth to do something like that?I dont want to mess to much with my system

Comment: Rinzwind's advice is always best! Other than that your CPU would also run nicely on a 64-bit OS.

Comment: @Vaois yes! I've been using it for like 1/2 a year now and it's the best of both worlds: 32 bits with all their apps (no messing with 64/32 mixing of apps) and the big ass memory :=)

Comment: i just wish its  easy enough to do. i dont want to screw my system

Comment: @Vaios It is easy!! it is! See the answer made by Vilmantas and Marco's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use PAE version of linux kernel to access more than 3.5GB of memory on 32-bit system.

For this, you need to install "linux-generic-pae" package either from synaptic or by issuing the following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-pae
```

Details are described here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE

To check if your processor supports PAE `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep pae` if it yields results you're good:

`flags: fpu vme de pse tsc msr` **pae** `mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 
clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc 
arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 
monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic 
popcnt xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow 
vnmi flexpriority ept vpid`

Comment: This should be installed on all 32bit machines with PAE enabled processors. To check if your processor supports PAE `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep pae` if it yields results you're good.

Comment: When i made my new installation this PAE thing installed automatically and i am now enjoying 8GB of ram.Thanks anyway